# Better Approach to use Pojo Class

Tags: android, pojo

I have  following Api Response

```
{
"page": 1,
"per_page": 3,
"total": 12,
"total_pages": 4,
"data": [
{
"id": 1,
"first_name": "George",
"last_name": "Bluth",
"avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/calebogden/128.jpg"
},
{
"id": 2,
"first_name": "Janet",
"last_name": "Weaver",
"avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/josephstein/128.jpg"
},
{
"id": 3,
"first_name": "Emma",
"last_name": "Wong",
"avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/olegpogodaev/128.jpg"
}
]
}
```

Where i have following response is common in most of the apis

```
 {
    "page": 1,
    "per_page": 3,
    "total": 12,
    "total_pages": 4,
```

Now i have following

```
public class ApiBasePojo {

    @SerializedName("page")
    @Expose
    private Integer page;
    @SerializedName("per_page")
    @Expose
    private Integer perPage;
    @SerializedName("total")
    @Expose
    private Integer total;
    @SerializedName("total_pages")
    @Expose
    private Integer totalPages;
    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    private List<UserPojo> userDetail = null;

    public Integer getPage() {
        return page;
    }

    public void setPage(Integer page) {
        this.page = page;
    }

    public Integer getPerPage() {
        return perPage;
    }

    public void setPerPage(Integer perPage) {
        this.perPage = perPage;
    }

    public Integer getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    public void setTotal(Integer total) {
        this.total = total;
    }

    public Integer getTotalPages() {
        return totalPages;
    }

    public void setTotalPages(Integer totalPages) {
        this.totalPages = totalPages;
    }

    public List<UserPojo> getData() {
        return userDetail;
    }

    public void setData(List<UserPojo> userDetail) {
        this.userDetail = userDetail;
    }
}
```

My concern is every pojo i have to repeat page,perpage ,total,total_pages so i am looking for common pojo where i can use it every pojo wherever required.
I have tried extending but its not possible .
Can any one help me.Thank you.

```
Updated
```

Suppose if i add common things in base and extend it in userPojo i cant set values in retrofit since  List is collection
As per me i can do this thing

```
public class MyBase {

    @SerializedName("page")
    @Expose
    private Integer page;
    @SerializedName("per_page")
    @Expose
    private Integer perPage;
    @SerializedName("total")
    @Expose
    private Integer total;
    @SerializedName("total_pages")
    @Expose
    private Integer totalPages;
    }


**UserPojo**  


public class UserPojo  {
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("first_name")
    @Expose
    private String firstName;
    @SerializedName("last_name")
    @Expose
    private String lastName;
    @SerializedName("avatar")
    @Expose
    private String avatar;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getAvatar() {
        return avatar;
    }

    public void setAvatar(String avatar) {
        this.avatar = avatar;
    }

}
```

**MyNewClass**

```
  public class MyNewClass extends  MyBase{


        @SerializedName("data")
        @Expose
        private List<UserPojo> userDetail = null;

        }
```

So Now i can use MyNewClass in my retrofit but here every time i need one new class like this

Comment: how about an abstract pojo or interface ;) ?

Comment: @WilomGfx.thanks for the comment .i am new to android .dont know much about it.if you have answer please post it .thank you

Comment: you can make page,per_page,total,total_pages as class level variables 
and you can create another class level variable List<UserPojo> list and add entries to this list

Comment: @SahilManchanda.you mean creating another class and extend base class then adding call List<UserPojo>.that i tired but i need to create every time extra class so thats problem

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you use inheritance for the common parameters by putting them in a base class or interface?  Most systems should be able to handle it.

Might I also point something out: (tl;dr)

There are two terms that I feel get confused a lot...  A Pojo is a Plain Old Java Object, it has no restrictions, it does not require any interface to be implemented or any patterns to be followed.  Often these are annotated as yours is.  These may (and should absolutely) contain business logic.

A Bean is different, each field of a bean has a setter and a getter and no business methods.

I mention the difference because it really matters in this case:

If you have your set of business classes with a good OO structure (Avoid setters, limit getters, encapsulate, etc) and simply annotate the members for use with your JSON data will already avoid the problems you are talking about (Your classes would have inherited from a common base class, right?)

Creating a framework of beans with setters and getters then inheritance will still work but you will also need a parallel set of classes to hold the business logic for your beans, which is fine I guess but at that point I'm not sure there is much of a benefit to keeping beans DRY that way, might want them to just clearly reflect your data if you are going through all that effort anyway.

Comment: .thanks.i updated my question if am wrong correct me thank you